# PHP : How to count the number of invalid emails in a CSV file

Tags: php, email, cakephp, count

I upload csv files from a VueJS frontend to a cakephp API. In those CSV files there are emails which need to get validated. But my problem appear after that, I would like to count the number of emails that are not valid in the CSV file and then put this value in a database.

Here is my code : I tested with "count()" but that doesn't work because I did it wrong I think.

```php
public function upload()
    {
        // POST ?
        $this->myMethodError(['post']);

        // reading parameters
        $uploadFileName = $this->request->getData('uploadFileName') ? $this->request->getData('uploadFileName') : '';
        $uploadFile = $this->request->getData('uploadFile') ? $this->request->getData('uploadFile') : '';


        // Uploaded with .csv extension ?
        $uploadFileExtension = pathinfo($this->request->data['name'])['extension']; // .csv ?
        if (!(in_array($uploadFileExtension, ['csv']))) {
            $this->myError(['error' => 'Wrong File extension: ' . $uploadFileExtension . '. .csv expected.']);
        }

        //copy the file in a repertory with date
        $destinationFile = TMP . "" . date("YmdHis") . "_annonceur_marque_campagne" . "." . $uploadFileExtension;

        if (move_uploaded_file($uploadFile['tmp_name'], $destinationFile)) {
            //---------------
            // Read .CSV
            //---------------
            if (($handle = fopen($destinationFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {

                //-------------------
                // Reading datas
                //--------------------
                $numrow = 0;

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $numrow++;

                    if (count($data) != 13) {
                        $this->myError(['error' => 'Structure de fichier invalide détectée ligne ' . $numrow]);
                        exit;
                    }

                    if ($numrow == 1) {
                        continue;
                    } // on saute les titres des colonnes

                    if($data[4] == "")
                    {
                        $this->myError(['error' => 'Le champs email est obligatoire. ligne ' . $numrow]);
                        exit;
                    }
                }

                //insert in database
                $uploadTable = TableRegistry::get('Locationsets');
                $upload = $uploadTable->newEntity();

                if(!filter_var($data[4], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true){
                    $upload->nbr_errors_email = count(filter_var($data[4], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
                }

                $upload->name = $uploadFileName;
                $upload->csv_files_dir = $destinationFile;

                if($uploadTable->save($upload)){
                    $uploadId = $upload->id;
                } else {
                    $this->myError(['error' => 'Insert failed']);
                }


                // return in Json
              $this->myOutput([$data]);

            } else {
                $this->myError(['error' => 'Reading csv file failed']);
            }
        } else {
            $this->myError(['error' => 'Csv file upload failed']);
        }
    }
```

This code add 1 in the database but that's not the result I should have.

Hope you can help.

**EDIT :**

An example of the content of `$data`

[image: data in csv]

Comment: Show us the contents of `$data`, or at least a sample from it

Comment: ```$data[4]``` is the field which contains emails. There are 2 bad emails inside it on a total of 37 lines

Comment: It seems that `$data` is one line of your database. So, when you count on `data[4]` that is a string, it will return 1. You should sum result for all data.

Comment: Intersting but I think that's because it stop to the first invalid email it finds and don't increment after it. How to resolve it ?

Comment: @Mathias Okay, then show us what `$data[4]` actually looks like. Use `print_r()` on your page, and update your question with the return.

Comment: I think we need more code for context. You're looking at `$data[4]`, for example, but haven't shown how `$data` even gets set.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I edited my post with the full upload function

Comment: Calling `exit;` when you have a mising e-mail probably doesn't help.

Comment: You are going through all the lines of data one at a time. Every time through that loop, `$data` is updated to have the current line, and only the current line. Everything that you do after the end of your `while` loop will have only the very last row of data available to it. So, you'll only check one row for the valid email address, and you'll only save one row of data.

Comment: Yes but if I do it inside the ```while``` loop, that will add all CSV rows in my database, and that don't what I want

Comment: Ah, I understand the data structure now. But you still need to check validity of each email address inside the loop.